# I need an algorithm to create vouchers based on date and amount of time

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need an algorithm that creates vouchers that is based on an internet kiosk timer. Basically, voucher should have the amount of time allowed encrypted into it. I was thinking of having the amount of time in hex at the start with a few random chars after it then a checksum at the end. However any other ideas are welcome

Comment: What have you tried already? What is not working or meeting your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use c# builtin libraries for encryption. Since you are the only entity that needs to encrypt/decrypt you can use either a asymetric key(public/private) schema, where you keep both keys private or a symmetric key solution.
Make sure the keys are sufficiently large so that they are not easy to break (at least 256 bits, preferably more).

You don't need to add random chars at the start. You don't need to add checksum at the end. The encryption library should fail to decrypt if the content has been tampered with (accidental character change, but will not stop a very determined attacker). If you want to be extra sure there's been no tampering generate an additional public/private keys and use them to sign the encrypted string.

If you don't care that users can see your voucher string, you can just put it in plain text and just use the libraries to sign it.

So all you need is to have a class that is serializable and contains all the fields of your voucher. Get the serialized string and pass it through the encryption/signing routines. When you get it backs use the same routines to make sure the string is authentic then deserialize it and you have your data.

The most important thing is to use the libraries correctly (follow the tutorials, instructions) and you keep your keys safe.